# jQuery validate dynamically created drop down select menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jquery-validate

So, I have a JSP loop creating select menus when a new record is created. The rule I am trying to accomplish is:

At least one of, could be 50 or more, of these is selected.  And that is it. Seems pretty simple to me but I am kinda stuck for some reason...do new rules for each select menu have to be created on the fly?  Can I just validate the entire group with 1 rule?

Here is the HTML/JSP:

```
<select class="reccomendations"
        name="selQuarantineRec"            
        required>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <c:forEach items="${qrntRecommendations}" var="qrntRec"
               varStatus="idx">
        <option value="${determination.id}_${ qrntRec.key }">
            <c:out value="${ qrntRec.value.name } "/>
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Here is the JS:

```
ns.util.validate('#nis_pest_form', {
    rules: {
        "selQuarantineRec": { //name of the select elements
            require_from_group: [1, '.reccomendations']
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for reading and helping out if you can!
Cheers
-b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"do new rules for each select menu have to be created on the fly?"*

Yes.  After the plugin is first initialized you can only declare new rules using methods provided by the plugin.  See [the `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules).

Create the new element and then call this…

```
$('#myselect').rules('add', {  // <- select a single element
    require_from_group: [1, '.reccomendations']
});
```

If you create more than one element at a time, then you must wrap it within a jQuery `.each()`…

```
$('.select').each(function() {  // <- select a group of elements
    $(this).rules('add', {
        require_from_group: [1, '.reccomendations']
    });
});
```

NOTE:

If you use the same `class` selector as for the `require_from_group`, the code can be condensed to this…

```
$('.reccomendations').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        require_from_group: [1, this]
    });
});
```

---

> *"Can I just validate the entire group with 1 rule?"*

No.  You must apply the rule to every element in the group.

---

**IMPORTANT**:

No matter how you create the elements and declare the rules, each element **must** contain a unique `name` attribute.  This is how the plugin keeps track of the inputs.

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for.  Very well explained and organized answer.  Thanks Sparky!!